# Can we use ToString() or Convert.ToString() in linq query with entity framwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can we use ToString() or Convert.ToString() in-line query when working with entity framework. Will it support all DB's.(mySQL,oracle,..) or it fails with anyone

```
  var pop = (from po in ctx.PurchaseOrders
       select new SearchItem
        {
          id = po.PurchaseOrderID,
          label = po.SupplierID.ToString, // or   Convert.Tostring(po.SupplierID)
          category = "purchaseorder"
       }).ToList();
```

Comment: ToString() or Convert.ToString() is used in C# code file is applicable to C# constructs. It has no connection with backend database. So , yes it will be supported by all DB's.

Answer (score 1):

ToString() or Convert.ToString() is used in C# code file and is applicable on C# constructs. It has no connection with backend database. So , yes it will be supported by all DB's.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are converting your queried data to list,You can do like this---

```
var pop = from po in ctx.PurchaseOrders
          select new SearchItem
          {
           id = po.PurchaseOrderID,
            label = po.SupplierID,
             category = po.purchaseorder
           }.AsEnumerable()  // Now, following Select will operate in memory
           .Select(n => new {
           n.PurchaseOrderID,
           SupplierID = t.SupplierID ?? t.SupplierID.ToString(),
           n.puchaseorder
 }).ToList();
```

The whole idea is once you get your queried data from database to in memory, you can use .ToString() method on that as i have stated here in the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple but important difference between them…

ToString() raise exception when the object is null

So in the case of object.ToString(), if object is null, it raise NullReferenceException.

Convert.ToString() return string.Empty in case of null object

(string) cast assign the object in case of null

So it depends upon your requirement, in my opinion you can use

```
var pop = (from po in ctx.PurchaseOrders
   select new SearchItem
    {
      id = po.PurchaseOrderID,
      label = (string)po.SupplierID,
      category = "purchaseorder"
   }).ToList();
```